# Ionic 2 change input component style md to windows

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

My client likes to use windows platform input field style to android platform. How can use windows input component style to android platform in ionic 2.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set a specific target behavior in `Config` object.

```
ionicBootstrap(AppRoot, customProviders, {
  iconMode: 'md',
  pageTransition: 'md',
});
```

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/

Here http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/platform-specific-styles/ you have a configuration for specific modes